# Ruby on Rails : : How to run an old project built in (Ruby -v1.9.2 - Rails -version 2.2.3) on Yosemite 10.10.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Having a setup of

> - `WEBrick 1.3.1`
> - `Ruby 2.2.2`
> - `Rails 3.2.22`
> - `5.6.22 MySQL`
> - `Yosemite 10.10.4`

I am trying to run an old Project built on `Ruby version 1.9.2` - `Rails 2.2.3` - `WEBrick 1.3.1` and once i type command : `rails server` i get an error :

> **Installing json 1.6.1 with native extensions**
>
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> `Could not find json-1.6.1 in any of the sources`
>
> `Run bundle install to install missing gems`

When i type 'bundle install' in the project directory i receive an error of :

> An error occurred while installing json (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.

What do i have to do in order to get this environment able to run this old project? Should i have to downgrade my `Rails version` .

Furthemore, by the time it fails to update gem  json -v '1.6.1' , is there any other way to update it?

Comment: Did you try to run `gem install json -v  '1.6.1'`?

Comment: Unfortunately it failed to build gem native extension .

generator.c:952:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *, long)' [-Wint-conversion]
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));

Comment: just remove 'json' from the Gemfile. json is included by default.

Comment: Thanks a million for the answer! How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, i managed to run my old project by installing `Ruby 1.9.3` with `Rails 3.1.1`. At first i thought that the problem was that

> gem install json -v '1.6.1' was failing.

But the reason that caused the error on the first place was that :

> You cannot install ruby `1.9.2p551` on `Yosemite 10.10.4`!!

Instead what i did was to

1. Install Ruby Version Management "`RVM`"
2. Install via RVM `ruby -v1.9.3p551`
3. Run command `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p551` in order to use this version
4. Run `bundle install` to load `railties 3.1.1 gem`
5. Run `rails server` on the "project" directory

Through these steps i am now able to view my application on browser !
Many thanks to [jkeuhlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3806046/jkeuhlen) & [boulder_ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276506/boulder-ruby) for the help.